# python nltk process killed

Tags: python, performance, nltk, google-compute-engine

I have a python script running on Google Compute Engine, 4 CPU 18gb RAM, but the script is killed after running, I know I'm loading a lot data, but I was hoping that 18gb of RAM would be enough, are there any optimizations that can be done to improve python to stop Ubuntu killing the python script?

```
word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:15000]

testing_set = featuresets[10000:]
training_set = featuresets[:10000]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
print((nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)

save_classifier = open("pickled/originalnaivebayes5k.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(classifier, save_classifier)
save_classifier.close()

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print((nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

save_classifier = open("pickled/MNB_classifier5k.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(MNB_classifier, save_classifier)
save_classifier.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory problem? Do you have any diagnostics of what is actually happening?

Comment: Looking at `kern.log` I can see
```Dec 19 19:06:28 instance-1 kernel: [ 3049.811780] Out of memory: Kill process 17400 (python) score 980 or sacrifice child
Dec 19 19:06:28 instance-1 kernel: [ 3049.820210] Killed process 17400 (python) total-vm:18467540kB, anon-rss:18100408kB, file-rss:940kB```

Comment: It's hard to give you good advice, since this is obviously not your actual script (eg. all_words and featuresets are not defined, word_features is never used). You can try not to create unnecessary copies of your data: eg. in the first line, you copy all keys into a throw-away list, then you create another partial copy through the slice. Or the trained classifiers: you save them to pickle, but don't delete the object, thus keeping it in memory while training the next one.

Comment: Try to find the critical parts: add progress info (with `print()` or `logging()`) and monitor the memory usage with a tool like `top` or `htop`. Or use a debugger to go through the program step by step.